# Accent errors in Navegation bar in Document Library web part in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript, encoding

I was following this [tutorial](http://robertmcquaig.com/sharepoint/document-library-breadcrumbs/) to add breadcrumbs in a documents library ..

but when I access to a folder with accents doesn't show correctly.

I know that is problem with encoding but I don't know where I should add charset = "utf-8"

I add in the first line but doesn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
```

I'm new in js so I don't know if i'm wrong..